# Appending dictionary into a list of tuples

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

Say I got the following dict :

```
d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
```

I want to create a function that appends each key and it's value into a list of tuples, so I coded:

```
def dict_to_list_of_tuples(dic):
    list_of_tuples = []
    for key in dic:
        list_of_tuples.append((key, dic[key]))
    return list_of_tuples
```

but I get the following output:

```
[('x', 1), ('y', 2), ('z', 3)]
```

while I want to get:

```
[(x, 1), (y, 2), (z, 3)]
```

Comment: You want to print that right?

Comment: @Netwave No, I want to save it in that form.

Comment: what are `x`, `y` and `z` then? variables? because I think you are missunderstanding your code there.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is simply `list(d.items())`:

```
>>> list(d.items())
[('x', 1), ('y', 2), ('z', 3)]
```

For **printing** in the format that you want just make the representation you want with `str.format`:

```
>>> "[{}]".format(f", ".join(f"({k}, {v})" for k,v in d.items()) )
'[(x, 1), (y, 2), (z, 3)]'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}

def dict_to_list_of_tuples(dic):
    list_of_tuples = []
    for key in dic:
        list_of_tuples.append((key, dic[key]))
    return list_of_tuples
print(dict_to_list_of_tuples(d))
print("[{}]".format(f", ".join(f"({k}, {v})" for k,v in dict_to_list_of_tuples(d)) ))
```